# MacTex 2016 Formatting Problem

Tags: formatting, mactex

I have recently updated to MacTex 2016. Following the update a mysterious extra wide margin has been added to the Inside and Bottom margin and all text and images on every page is squeezed into the upper right quadrant of a page in the pdf output. Is this a bug? Anyone have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,british,twoside,openany,pagesize=false,headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.25pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
\clearpairofpagestyles% remove default header and footer content
\cehead{Ben Francis}
\cohead{\rightmark}% section in header
\ofoot{} %Author Name
\ifoot{} % Chapter Number
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in,
    verbose,
    margin=0.75in,
    headheight=0.1in,
    headsep=0.15in,
    footskip=0.45in,
    }
\renewcommand*\raggedsection{\centering}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} %for headings
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\small}

\linespread{1.05}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\addchap{ONE}
\addsec{First section}
\lipsum
\addchap{TWO}
\addsec{Second section}
\lipsum
\addchap{THREE}
\addsec{Third section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: using luatex? if so add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as first line, does that fix it?

Comment: Hi David - thanks. Yep ... sorted. Never had to use this 'requirement' specifically stated before the update to MacTex 2016, so would never have thought of it.

Comment: Actually I don't see the margin but geometry package is still not updated for luatex 95 (as used in texlive 2016) the new luatex is _very_ incompatible with previous versions and breaks most packages assuming pdftex compatible behaviour. Until they are updated, `luatex85.sty` offers a certain level of compatibility

Comment: Thanks - makes sense now. Makes life a bit more complex though (lol) as an author writing most of my time it's frustrating when things are not updated and I am forced into a dead stop. But thanks must go to the developers who need to address these problems - a thankless task that deserves far more 'reward' than they receive...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until `geometry` package is updated, you can use

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
```

on the first line to offer a compatibility layer between the new luatex and pdftex.

**`luatex85` is no longer required with `geometry` 2018/03/24 v5.7**